# How can i see conda env in oh my posh theme in powershell?

Tags: anaconda, conda, oh-my-posh

I have install oh-my-posh, and i use blue-owl theme. From documentation i add these lines of code to json file;

```
{
    "type": "python",
    "style": "powerline",
    "powerline_symbol": "\uE0B0",
    "foreground": "#100e23",
    "background": "#906cff",
    "template": " \uE235 {{ .Full }}"
},
```

[image]

But i can't see my conda environment. I search about it but can't find any thing.
Can you help me to add my conda env to powershell?

I try to add following line:

```
{
    "type": "command",
    "style": "blue",
    "powerline": "left",
    "foreground": "#F0DB4F",
    "background": "#4F5D75",
    "properties": {
        "command": "conda activate base",
        "leading_icon": " "
    }
},
```

But nothing change. I can't see conda env.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/python#properties):

```json
{
    "type": "python",
    "style": "powerline",
    "powerline_symbol": "\uE0B0",
    "foreground": "#100e23",
    "background": "#906cff",
    "template": " \uE235 {{ .Full }} {{ if .Venv }}{{ .Venv }}{{ end }}",
    "properties": {
        "fetch_virtual_env": true
    }
},
```

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer on GitHub, thank you so much again.